# Facing difficulties to write a sql query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

We have three tables users,answers and stretches. When someone login to our system we stored user_id,created_at and updated_at in stretches table and when he/she logout updated deleted at in the same row.

Session time 30 minutes.

### users table

- id
- f_name
- l_name
- email

### answers table

- id
- user_id
- body
- created_at
- updated_at

### stretches table

- id
- user_id
- created_at
- updated_at
- deleted_at

Now i want to get only those rows from the stretches table where an answer has been given. I wrote this query but it takes to much time but did not return accurate data.

```
  $query = "select count(a.id), a.user_id
      from answers a
      where a.created_at in 
            (select s.created_at 
                from stretches s 
                   where s.created_at >= a.created_at
            ) group by a.user_id";
  $results = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```

I'd be curious to hear how some of you write this query.

**Answers table**

```
id | body | user_id |    created_at    |    updated_at 
10 | text |   10    | 2015-10-10 0:0:0 | 2015-10-10 0:0:0
```

**Stretches Table**

```
id | user_id |    created_at    |    updated_at    |    deleted_at 
 1 |   10    | 2015-10-00 0:0:0 | 2015-10-10 0:0:0 | 2015-10-20 0:0:0
```

Now i want to get those rows from `stretches` table where an answer has been given.

Query results should be:

```
id | user_id |    created_at    |   updated_at    |    deleted_at 
 1 |   10    | 2015-10-10 0:0:0 |2015-10-10 0:0:0 | 2015-10-10 0:0:0
```

Comment: Can you add some example of data in `answers` and `stretches` table and you expected output based on that?

Comment: Answers Table
id       body    user_id    created_at               updated_at
10      text      10            2015-10-10 0:0:0     2015-10-10 0:0:0

Stretches Table
id     user_id    created_at             updated_at             deleted_at
1      10            2015-10-00 0:0:0   2015-10-10 0:0:0  2015-10-20 0:0:0

Now i want to get those rows from stretches table where an answer has been given.

Results
id      user_id     created_at               updated_at               deleted_at
1       10             2015-10-10 0:0:0    2015-10-10 0:0:0      2015-10-10 0:0:0

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you. SQL query below will return only those records from table Stretches where answer was given to user. Use operator **JOIN**, it will do filter work for you.

```
SELECT S.user_id, COUNT(*) as answers_count FROM Stretches AS S
    JOIN Answers AS A ON S.user_id = A.user_id
GROUP BY S.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
SELECT DISTINCT Stretches.* FROM Stretches
    JOIN Answers ON Stretches.user_id = Answers.user_id
GROUP BY Stretches.user_id
```